# No log4j.xml in fredhopper installation media

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

There is no log4j.xml in fredhopper installation media for SmartTarget 2014 SP1,

From where can I get it. As per documentation it suggests to contact fredhopper, but it must be by default provided.

Comment: Could you make the question as complete as possible? I guess you are using Fredhopper on premise and you talking about this documentation topic: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-3ABFE8AB-1F2D-4B24-B57C-CF097D93CE3F

Comment: I checked on my own developer machine, I do not have a  <BASE_DIRECTORY>\data\instances\<INDEXER>\config\log4j.xml either. I never missed it though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no log4j.xml located `<base_fredhopper_directory>/data/instances/<instance_name>/config`, then you can copy the file into this directory from `<base_fredhopper_directory>/data/installations/<installation>/etc`.

Copying the file to `<base_fredhopper_directory>/data/instances/<instance_name>/config` allows the file here to take precedence over the file located in `<base_fredhopper_directory>/data/installations/<installation>/etc`, but be aware that the file then applies to that instance only. (E.g. if you wanted to configure the logging on both an indexer and a live server, you'd need to copy the file to, and configure, each instance separately).

This does indeed only apply to an on-premise installation of Fredhopper. Log4J configuration for cloud installations works slightly differently, but won't cover that here as I'll assume (as Jan has) that you're using an on-premise installation.

Comment: Thanks Patrick,

But I cant even find location you mentioned <base_directory>/installations/<installation>/config

Comment: I've put the wrong directory in there, so I suppose that would bee why, apologies. Please see my edited answer.